# Error creating symbolic matrix of zeros in matlab

Tags: matlab, subscript

I'm trying to create a symbolic matrix initially filled with zeros. The error I'm getting is:

> "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers
>   or logicals."

The line of code that is producing the error is:

```
v = sym(zeros(5, 4)).
```

If I run this line of code in the Command Window, it works as expected. But, as part of a function in a script it produces the error.

Why this is?

Comment: please share your function with us in a [mcve]

Comment: You probably defined an array named `sym` in your function, overwriting the `sym` function...